# How to override "selected state" image in MKAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've got annotation views with custom pin images on a map. When I tap and hold on a pin, my custom image disappears and is replaced by the default red pin. This default image appears in its selected (highlighted) state (it looks slightly darker). How can I prevent the selected state image from replacing my custom image?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution: I was incorrectly using the class MKPinAnnotationView instead of MKAnnotationView for my annotations. When the custom pin was tapped, causing it to darken (in its highlight state), the custom image was being replaced by the default pin that underlines MKPinAnnotationView.